# Haskell - zip 2 lists

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that zips two lists together. I have the following code:

```
zip' :: [a]->[b]->[(a,b)]
zip' _ [] = []
zip' [] _ = []
zip' (x:xs)(y:ys)=(x,y) zip'(xs ys)
```

The problem is that when I compile the code I get a lot of errors

> Couldn't match expected type [b]->t0 with actual type a
>
> The function xs is applied to one argument

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Sorry if this may sound like  stupid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to append `(x,y)` to the return value:

```
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y):zip' xs ys
```

Otherwise, it makes no sense syntactically since you're not `cons` (:)ing the x,y you matched to the return value.

[Fiddle](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fae9189a995296a)

Answer (score 7):

> Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

The code

```
(x,y) zip'(xs ys)
```

means: take the *function* `(x,y)` and apply it to two arguments, the first being `zip'` and the second being the result of applying the *function* `xs` to `ys`.

Since `(x,y)` is not a function,  this triggers a type error. Further, `xs` is not a function, so another type error will be caused by its application.